# File partially sent in c

Tags: c, linux, windows, file-upload, tcp

I'm trying to send files using TCP from a windows client to a Linux server in C.

The size of the buffer I use to send the data is 65535. When the size of the file exceeds this value, I get an error saying 'connection reset by peer' or the error code 10054. When the size of the file is less than 65535 bytes, the server receives only a part of it (usually 2760 bytes).

I just want to send files with a maximum size of 50 MB.

This is the part of the windows client that I use to send data:

```
    char *fileName;     // pointer to filename
    char buf[65535];        // buffer
    int fileSize;   // # bytes to send

    for(i = 0; i < ARRAYSIZE; i++) {
        if(selectList[i] != NULL) {
            // select file
            fileName= selectList[i];                        // get path and filename from selectList
            printf("=============================================\nSending: %s\n", fileName);
            filefd = fopen(fileName, "rb");                 // open file
            if(filefd == NULL) {
                printf("File %s not found\n", fileName);
                exit(1);
            }

            // read and send file
            memset(buf, '\0', 65535);
            while((fileSize= fread(buf, sizeof(char), 65535, filefd)) > 0) {          // read file
                if((numberOfBytes = send(sockfd, buf, fileSize, 0)) < 0) {                                // send buffer
                    printf("send: %s (Error: %d)\n", filename, WSAGetLastError());
                    break;
                }
                printf("#bytes = %i \n", numberOfBytes);
                memset(buf, '\0', 65535);
            }
            printf("File %s send!\n", filename);

            // close file after sending it
            if(fclose(filefd) < 0) {
                printf("fclose: %i", WSAGetLastError());
            }
        } else if(selectList[0] == NULL) {
            printf("no files selected");
        }
    }
```

The selectList contains multiple strings such as: C:\Windows\test.txt

The recieve part of the Linux server:

```
    char* fr_name = "/home/MtFS/UploadedFiles/public/testFile.gif";
    FILE *fr = fopen(fr_name, "wb");

    if(fr == NULL)
        printf("[Open_File]file %s cannot be created\n", fr_name);
    else {
        bzero(revbuf, LENGTH);
        int fr_block_sz = 0;

        while((fr_block_sz = recv(nsockfd, revbuf, LENGTH, 0)) > 0) {
            int write_sz = fwrite(revbuf, sizeof(char), fr_block_sz, fr);
            if(write_sz < fr_block_sz) {
                error("[Write] error\n");
            }
            bzero(revbuf, LENGTH);
            if (fr_block_sz == 0 || fr_block_sz != 512) {
                break;
            }
        }

        if(fr_block_sz < 0) {
            if (errno == EAGAIN) {
                printf("[Receive] time out\n");
            }
            else {
                printf("[Receive] error\n");
                exit(1);
            }
        }

        printf("[Receive] succesfull\n");
        fclose(fr);
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem are those 3 lines of code. That's not the correct way to know that you're done:

```
        if (fr_block_sz == 0 || fr_block_sz != 512) {
            break;
        }
```

Also you check against 512 instead of LENGTH. But only 0 means that you're done (assuming your connection is not NONBLOCKED.)

As a side note: you do not have to clear your buffers (bzero, memset) before using them with a read since the read/recv will overwrite the content of the buffers anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I've changed the if-statement to 

if (fr_block_sz == 0)

the size of the recieved file is correct, but the file itself is empty/corrupt. Any clues?

Comment: Thank you it works now, I accidentally changed something else. if (fr_block_sz == 0) works.

Comment: Errors are detected with -1, the read/recv will return -1 and set the errno variable. For more info, try `man 2 read` and `man 2 recv` in a Linux console.

Answer (score 0):

I think the culprit is this line in your server

```
if (fr_block_sz == 0 || fr_block_sz != 512) {
```

`fr_block_sz` cab be anything between `1` to `65535` - the size block that you sent.

In your code, when its not `512` so your server is terminating the connection.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I've changed the if-statement to

if (fr_block_sz == 0)

the size of the recieved file is correct, but the file itself is empty/corrupt. Any clues?